# How to create custom hollow object?

Tags: modeling, mesh

You are watching the heart's back part it is currently looking ugly. I want to cover the back part of the heart with a hollow object. I tried with the hollow sphere but the shape of the image is not exactly spherical.

So how can I create custom hollow object that can cover the heart. I would like to connect the edges that I marked in the red color in the heart below.
[image]

Comment: Duplicate the part to be covered in edit mode and make a separate object from it. Then edit as needed. That may be the simplest starting point.

Comment: Thanks @Timaroberts for the suggestion. Since I am new to blender I don't have much knowledge about it.

If I do the duplicate of the selected area then how to extrude or join the vertices so that to give the curve area?

Comment: Try the *Grid Fill* operator but don't expect miracles. You should probably watch some tutorials on organic modelling